# Checking items in two lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I am having some problem when trying to check for duplicate in two lists. What I am trying to do is I check if the distSPUItem contains ID in prodSubstitute list, then perform something. Here is the code:

```
    List<ProductPacking> prodSubstitute = new List<ProductPacking>();
    List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> distSPUItem = new List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();
    for (int count = 0; count < prodSubstitute.Count; count++)
        {
             if (!distSPUItem.Contains(prodSubstitute[count].id))
             {
                //Perform something here
             }
        }
```

However it tells me that the best overload method.Contain has invalid arguments. Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not the complete error message. Best overload of what?

Comment: Which method does it flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list distSPUItem only contains objects of type DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems, however you are checking if the list contains an int-variable (your ID). In the .Contains-method you need to pass an object of type DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems, aswell.

If you only want to check for the ID, you can use LINQ

```
if(!distSPUItem.Any(i => i.ID == prodSubstitute[count].id))
{
    // perform something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For best performance you can left join the two lists on the id key and check for null.

```
var q = from p in prodSubstitute
        join d in distSPUItem on p.id equals d.id into g
        from x in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where x == null
        select p;

foreach(var item in q)
{
   //Perform something here
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works but it is slightly complicated as compared to the answer above. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Gwen Yes, but `join` has O(1) lookup compared to O(N) for `Any`

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
List<ProductPacking> prodSubstitute = new List<ProductPacking>();
    List<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems> distSPUItem = newList<DistributionStandardPackingUnitItems>();

                var q = prodSubstitute.Where(item => distSPUItem.Select(item2 => item2).Contains(item));
                var y = prodSubstitute .Except(distSPUItem ); // y will have 2, since 2 are not included in list2

                foreach (var i in q)
                {
                   //Perform something here
                }
```